# Wget Downloading Issue?

Tags: batch-file, wget

I have a problem with `wget` or my `code`..

```
wget -N --no-check-certificate "https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjf0ka54yuwz81d/Test.zip?dl=0"
```

The `-N` syntax is supposed to be downloading the file 'only' if the file is newer in terms of modification date but, It downloads the file every time I run the script. I see `Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off` at the end of the output.

I don't get it as, When I upload/update a file on dropbox it does change and show "Modified" date-time but, wget doesn't get it or what?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9221/how-to-work-around-missing-last-modified-headers

Comment: @alfasin Thanks but, `-c` parameter does not actually help me. because the file on the dropbox can be `smaller` or `bigger` than the `local file` and from what I get the `-c` parameter will only download the file if the file is `bigger` on the server (It will consider it as an `incomplete download`) and will not download if the server file is `smaller` than the `local file`.

Comment: Did you read the 2nd answer as well?

Comment: @alfasin Yes, but that was answered 4 years back. There must be something I could use. I wouldn't mind using another utility, if it gets the job done.

Comment: its in fact not included in the response header (as you can see when you run this `wget --no-check-certificate -S https://www.dropbox.com/s/qjf0ka54yuwz81d/Test.zip?dl=0` or in a web browser in developer tools), so for some reason Dropbox does not provide this information to wget so it won't work.

Comment: @PupaRebbe Thanks, I knew something was wrong there, It was either that or my code was wrong. I was wondering if `curl` can do this job?